# Create new worksheet for each column within one excel file in R

Tags: r, excel, loops, worksheet

I am trying to take an excel file I have (let's say it has 4 columns named "one","two","three","four" and the excel file is called "test") and make a separate worksheet for each column.
So within in my "test" file, I would have 4 worksheets. In the first worksheet would be the all of the values in column "one", the next worksheet would be all of the values in column "two", etc.

I tried using a loop like this:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(test)){
write.xlsx(test[i,,], file="filename.xlsx", sheetName=names(test)[i])
}
```

But it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One concern is you have two commas in the bracketed data frame reference, and the first bracketed argument will grab the row not the column. Also, unlike data frames, vectors do not have column names:

```
colnames(mtcars[,1])
NULL
```

First, I'll show the `openxlsx` code I used to produce what I believe you wanted. Then I show code with the `xlsx` package given the corruption error you are seeing with `openxlsx`. I hope the comments express sufficiently what the code does.

### openxlsx package version

```
library(openxlsx)
# Create the workbook data structure as wb
wb <- createWorkbook()
for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)){
# shtname will be the ith column name in mtcars  
  shtname = names(mtcars)[i]
# add a sheet to wb that is named the ith column name
  addWorksheet(wb, shtname)
# Turn the ith column vector of mtcars into a dataframe 
# so we can give the object a column name
  mtcars_col_frm <-  data.frame(mtcars[,i])
  colnames(mtcars_col_frm) <- shtname
# write into that sheet the ith column of mtcars
  writeData(wb, i, mtcars_col_frm, colNames = TRUE)
}
# save all of the created sheets into a workbook
# Note that I used overwrite = TRUE to avoid 
# "File already exists" error you may experience
saveWorkbook(wb, file="filename.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

### xlsx package version

```
library(xlsx)
# Create the workbook data structure as wb
wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook()
for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)){
  # shtname will be the ith column name in mtcars  
  shtname = names(mtcars)[i]
  # add a sheet to wb that is named the ith column name
  sht <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, shtname)
  # Turn the ith column vector of mtcars into a dataframe 
  # so we can give the object a column name
  mtcars_col_frm <-  data.frame(mtcars[,i])
  colnames(mtcars_col_frm) <- shtname
  # write into that sheet the ith column of mtcars
  xlsx::addDataFrame(x = mtcars_col_frm, sheet = sht, row.names = FALSE)
}
# save all of the created sheets into a workbook
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file="filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: I tried running this code with my data, but when I open it in excel, it says "The workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt"

Comment: It is working for me. Maybe an update of the openxlsx package is needed?

Comment: My data has 200 columns, do you think that could be why?

Comment: Maybe. Does my code work? I used the mtcars data frame that comes with R.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you run the exact same code as mine - using mtcars? Also, what do you see when you enter packageVersion("openxlsx")? I see 4.0.17.

Comment: Yes I ran it using mtcars.I also have version 4.0.17

Comment: Maybe this is an issue that only affects some versions of Excel. I see there are open issues for openxlsx that include "corrupted": https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+corrupt. You might try the xlsx package.

Comment: I just added code for the xlsx package you can try. If that fails, you can modify my code to see if the recent writexl package will work. Please accept my answer if it's sufficiently helpful.